# Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1

Tags: php

A web page is returning Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1.....on line 175 whe running the function below:

```
function genRandomString() {

    $length = 26;

    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    $string = "";    

    for ($p = 1; $p < $length; $p++) {

    $string .=$characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))-1]; // <-- LINE 175

    }

    return $string;

    }
```

What might be the problem on the line 175?

Comment: Well `mt_rand(0, …)` might return 0. Subtract 1 from that, and you might end up with an index value outside of the index range of the string.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract from `strlen`, not from `mt_rand`:

```
mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)
```

---

```
function genRandomString($length = 26) {
    $characters = implode('', range(0, 9)) . implode('', range('a', 'z'));

    $string = '';
    $maxIndex = strlen($characters) - 1;

    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, maxIndex)]; // <-- LINE 175
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Subtracting from mt_rand and not strlen solved the problem

mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)

Thank you, @Justinas

Comment: @HenryOmondi Please accept answer if it helps you